# How to use redirect with parameter in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have this function in views.py:

```
def detel_kar(request, id):
   detel = {}
   detel['detels'] = DipPegawai.objects.filter(PegID=id)
   detel['kels']=DipKeluargaPeg.objects.filter(PegID_id=id)
   return render(request, 'karyawan/detel_kar.html', detel)
```

I then have a function to insert data with parameter id by getting a primary key from elsewhere.

```
def tambah_kel(request, id):
   kar = DipPegawai.objects.get(PegID=id)
   if request.method == "POST":
       kel=DipKeluargaPeg(PegID=kar)
       form = datakeluarga(request.POST,instance=kel)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save(commit=True)
           return redirect('detel_kar')
   else:
       form = datakeluarga()
   return render(request, 'karyawan/tambah_kel.html', {'form': form, 'kars': kar})
```

How to redirect to `detel_kar` view? if i use this code in `tambah_kel` function

```
return redirect('detel_kar')
```

it will return anerror

```
Reverse for 'detel_kar' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^tambah/$', views.tambah, name='tambah_kar'),
    url(r'^karyawan/detel_kar/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.detel_kar, name='detel_karyawan'),
    url(r'^karyawan/edit_kar/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.edit_kar, name='edit_karyawan'),
    url(r'^karyawan/del_kar/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.del_kar, name='del_karyawan'),
    url(r'^karyawan/tambah_kel/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.tambah_kel, name='tambah_keluarga'),
]
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `urls.py`.

Comment: Post your `urls.py`

Comment: I have post my urls.py @solarissmoke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `urls.py`, you have defined:

```
url(r'^karyawan/detel_kar/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.detel_kar, name='detel_karyawan'),
```

i.e., the view that calls the function `detel_kar()` is named `'detel_karyawan'`. This is the name you need to use in your redirect:

```
return redirect('detel_karyawan')
```

However the view expects an ID, so you must supply an ID when calling it:

```
return redirect('detel_karyawan', id=id)
```

(Where `id` is determined based on the logic in your view).

Comment: Done. Thank you @solarissmode